# After laravel installation localhost doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, .htaccess

so i am having to do a project on laravel and I installed it all right and it works fine (can be accessed via localhost:8000) however I cannot access localhost. I am trying to run a laravel installation and wordpress concurrently. also Wordpress and localhost worked fine before I installed laravel.

My Laravel installation is in html/laravel and Wordpress in html/wordpress.

I have been trying out a lot of things I came across online to no avail. 
The .htaccess file in my /html is empty. Some of the links suggested that I have to write new .conf files for each installation and yet others suggested me to change .htaccess. nothing helped. 
I am at a loss. Any help much appreciated. Thanks

I am on a ubuntu16.4 machine.

Comment: Check you configuration and correct it.

Comment: Why would you place a wordpress installation and a laravel installation both in an html folder. Besides running laravel needs the command `php artisan serve` to run on `localhost:8000`.

Comment: yes I used `php artisan serve` and was able to access laravel installation. however i cant access localhost

Comment: Could you show the `error` localhost is returning. Besides wich program are you using for running the normal `localhost`

Comment: The error is 404 and I use Apache for localhost.

Comment: alright so that means that the page is not found. did you check the `url`. Besides are you using WAMP or XAMPP for localhost or are you running just apache?

Comment: I use lamp. Yes the URL is `localhost` for normal localhost and laravel runs on `localhost:8000`

Comment: @Deathstorm I cant seem to solve this problem. i have been reading elsewhere and this problem seems to be an old one and yet the problem persists. Noting helped. Please do help.

Comment: @parshu give me a moment to startup my pc and i'll take a look (:

Comment: @Deathstorm eagerly waiting for some insight :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from the chat we had in the comments we came to the following conclusions:

1. You're using a linux(ubuntu) server.
2. You're using `lamp`, more information about lamp can be found [here](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/LAMP-Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP)
3. You're trying to run `lamp` (localhost) and `laravel` (localhost:8000) together.

With this information i think the issue is within the laravel and localhost application combined. There are a couple of things we should keep in mind

1. To run `laravel` on a localhost:8000 environment be sure to run the following command `php artisan serve`.
2. The configuration as told in older answers should be set right in `laravel`

   - Give 775 permission to storage & bootstrap folder inside laravel folder and access url through html/laravel/public. *credits to: @vijay_Kashyap
3. Check the .conf file of apache and make sure all items are set right.

   - Look for the file: `000-default.conf` -> [tutorial](https://dev.to/rizwan_saquib/how-to-create-lamp-stack-with-laravel-on-digital-ocean-server)

Even if all these things are set correctly the mistake could still appear due to wrong `url-rewriting` or the server that clashes with the `laravel` installation.

If you're sure that the above settings are set correctly you should take a look at the configuration of your `lamp` installation and the setup steps of `laravel`. Think about some of the following things:

- Are the right packages installed
- Is everything up to date -> command: `sudo apt-get upgrade`, `sudo apt-get update` (use `-dist` in case you're not completely sure).
- Is Apache's mod rewrite enabled? -> `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
- Did you install `composer` -> `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`
- check `my_app.conf` (if exists in your case).

If none of these things work for you it maybe would be an idea to restart from the beginning. Maybe you've made some changes to files you didn't need to change but forgot about them due to frustration etc. (happend to me the first time i installed multiple application types).

I would also like to refer you to [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/) and [this tutorial about lamp](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/tutorials/wa-lamp/wa-lamp.html)

Since i'm not able to review the server for myself i can't give you much more information at the moment. Do ask questions if anything is unclear or new errors occur.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a ton for taking the time out to help me. very much appreciated. I finally after iterating through all of the above resorted to reinstall apache. Apparently i had messed up with its config files and didn't know what's where. Any how all things back to normal and i can now go back to work. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer you to change permission after every install. It's because of most folders should be normal "755" and files, "644".

Laravel requires some folders to be writable for the web server user.

Answer (score 0):

Give 775 permission to storage & bootstrap folder inside laravel folder and access url through html/laravel/public.

If you want to run directly from html/laravel folder location, copy rename server.php to index.php

Comment: The laravel installation works fine. would changing permission for laravel installation have any effect on the localhost ??

Comment: did this and it didn't help. I have been reading everywhere and can't seem to fix this. Please help